# What is the k-SAT problem?

Tags: sat

First of all I am of course aware of the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem

However I still do not understand exactly what the problem is. To demonstrate that I've tried, I think it is as follows but I am not sure:

> The problem of checking whether a given boolean equation with k distinct
>   variables is satisfiable.

For example, is this an instance of the 3-sat problem?

```
x OR y OR z
```

Comment: I'm not surprised you can't follow that article; what a mess!  3SAT asks whether a formula $\wedge_{i} (x_{i1} \lor x_{i2} \lor x_{i3})$ is satisfiable, where each $x_{ij}$ is either a variable or its negation.

Comment: The Wikipedia article does give an example of a 3SAT formula, if you scroll down.

Comment: @Andas: Thanks. @Robin: I'm aware of that, but an example of a 3SAT formula doesn't define what a 3SAT formula is - hence the example problem I provided (which is obviously not NP-complete - that's partially why I was confused by that section of the article).

Comment: Can someone explain why this question was downvoted so I can improve it?

Comment: I voted the question down because it can be answered by consulting any textbook of computational complexity theory or even the Wikipedia article you linked to.  (I recommend a textbook because I do not think that that Wikipedia article is written very clearly.)

Comment: Vote for close. Same reason as Tsuyoshi.

Comment: Voted to close.  Same reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that's not what you thought!

The "K" in K-SAT is not related to the number of variables in the formula; rather, it limits the number of "literals" in each "clause".

Let's define the terms:

atom = the same thing you called variable; e.g. "x", "y", "z", etc.

literal = an atom or its negation; e.g "x" or "$\neg$x".

clause = a disjunction of literals; e.g. $(x \vee y \vee \neg z \vee w)$.

CNF: A formula is said to be in Conjunctive Normal Form (CNF) if it consists of AND's of several clause. For instance, $(x \vee y) \wedge (y \vee \neg z \vee w)$ is a CNF formula.

**The followin problem is K-SAT:**
Given a CNF formula $f$, in which each clause has *exactly* K literals, decide whether or not $f$ is satisfiable. That is, whether there is a an assignment to the atoms such that $f$ evaluates to TRUE.

See also *Mike Jason B Punkt*'s answer in this post.

Comment: Thanks - consise and informative. So a boolean formula is a k-SAT formula iff it is a CNF with at most k literals per clause?

Comment: Not "**at most** k literals per clause", but "**exactly** k literals per clause". Other than that, you're right.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Yeah I was wondering about that but Mike's answer says "3-SAT is the satisfiability-problem, where each clause in the CNF has (at most) 3 literals."

Comment: Both the “at most k literals” definition and the “exactly k distinct literals” definition are used in literature.  The distinction is not important in most cases, with a notable exception of approximation algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

k-SAT limits the size of the clauses. E.g. 3-SAT is the satisfiability-problem, where each clause in the CNF has (at most) 3 literals. 1-SAT is in L, 2-SAT is in NL. For any k > 2, k-SAT is NP-complete.